# Unauthorized Error During AWS to Google Cloud Storage Migration Using Transfer Service Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

AWS credentials look fine as I have given full S3 access for that access key. It is able to detect no of files and size, but transfer fails. I am not sure whether it is AWS permission issue or Google Cloud Storage permission issue. Below I have added logs. Please check and let me know if you have encountered the problem and how to solve it.

Transfer operation details
Status
Failed
Files
0 of 24
Bytes
0 B of 1.76 MB

Transfer files with prefix
images/*****************/
Exclude files with prefix
Synchronisation method
—
Time-based filtering
Maximum age
1 hour
Minimum age
—
Errors
UNKNOWN: (showing 5 of 24 failures)

Object: s3_fetch:images/*****************/*****************_large.jpg

Details: Http error code: Unauthorized.

Object: s3_fetch:images/*****************/*****************_medium.jpg

Details: Http error code: Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out.  You must give your service account (described here [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/configure-access)) the "Storage Admin" IAM role.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. Not sure if there was an issue at AWS or at GCP.

I created a new transfer job but instead of pointing to a previously created GCP bucket, I created a new one - thinking it might be a permission issue. This worked. But I also recreated the old jobs that had been failing, and they also worked. Permissions on both buckets look similar.

---

I'm getting the same error when I try to create a transfer job. All permissions seem to be ok, but I still get this Unknown error: Unauthorized.